# Delphi 10.2 Tokyo VCL sources

Tags: delphi, vcl

I've just installed RAD 10.2 Tokyo, from the official ISO, but using a trial period serial number. It says "Architect" when I start it (though I wanted to trial Entreprise edition).

Now inside Delphi's folder, when I go to sources, I find a few subfolders like rtl, but no VCL subfolder.

Does anyone have these files? Am I missing them because I installed a trial version, did Embarcadero stop providing them? In my old Delphi XE2, I also have FireMonkey framework sources, but here, nothing...

Comment: Trial does not provide access to the unit source code. You receive only precompiled units (no matter if VCL or RTL).

Comment: How likely do you think it is that EMBA would give you all the source with a free trial, do you think?

Comment: @MartynA Turbo Delphi was a free version of Delphi 2006 that actually included the VCL and RTL source code, so it might be possible. But since they regretted that step later on, it's not likely they repeated it.

Comment: @dummzeuch:  Thanks for reminding me.  They seems to have a habit of back-pedalling on freebies - Interbase springs to mind.

Comment: @MartynA How likely is it people could obtain the sources another way? It's just while I was trying it I got very annoyed that I couldn't browse the sources as I usually did, so wanted to be sure if I buy it sources are still available. Now the funny part is they don't even include Indy sources, which was the thing I missed the most when trying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trial version does not provide sources. You get the sources when you purchase. Note that the starter edition also does not provide sources.