# listview with progress bar (FMX)

Tags: android, ios, listview, firemonkey, c++builder

I would like to add a progress bar to each item in a `TListView`, similar to the picture below (that is from Audible app):

[image]

Is this doable with `TListView`, or should I be using some other control?  I'm working with FireMonkey in C++Builder, and will target iOS and maybe Android.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118359/custom-drawing-of-tcustomlistbox-items, the question has been changed since the answer, but the answer covers your situation.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, I've looked your sample over but I don't know how to apply here in C++ Builder.